# thread checking problem

Tags: java

I do need help.
I'm wracking my brain in order to understand how threads work.

I'm wondering what's wrong with this code?
My application has two threads. One thread starts when the user press button A, the other one
starts when the B button is chosen. If one button is enabled the other one is disabled.

Now I'd like to be able to warn the user that a thread is still running whenever he/she tries to
exit the program.

the code is....actually even though nothing is running the user is unable to exit..
Thank you very much

> exitAction = new
>   AbstractAction("Exit") {
>
> ```
>         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>
>           Thread thRunning = Thread.currentThread();
>
>
>         if (thRunning.isAlive()) {
> ```
>
> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ProgAu.this,
>   "Be careful.Press STOP before
>   exiting",
>                       "Process running", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
>
> ```
>     }
>      else {
>
>             System.exit(0);}
>
>         }
>     };
> ```

--
This is one of the thread I'm refering to....
What should I do in order to detect its behaviour?

> class RecThread extends Thread {
>
> ```
>     public void run() {
>
>         recFile = new File("rec.wav");
>
>         AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = null;
>         fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
>
>
>
>         try {
>
>             targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
>
>
>             targetDataLine.start();
>
>
>             AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine),
> ```
>
> fileType, recFile);
>
> ```
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             showException(e);
>         }
>
>
>         playAction.setEnabled(true);
>         stopPlayAction.setEnabled(false);
>   recAction.setEnabled(true);
>         stopRecAction.setEnabled(false);  
>
>
>
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 8):

What's wrong with the code is that it will *always* warn the user. Look at this:

```
Thread thRunning = Thread.currentThread();
```

That means you're looking at the *currently running* thread. The one that's executing that method call, and continuing to execute `actionPerformed`. How could that possibly *not* be running? It's like someone asking out loud whether the person who is speaking is dead.

When you start off your other thread (wherever that is) you need to keep a reference to *that* thread... that's the one you need to test for liveness. Or alternatively (and preferably IMO) the background threads could keep increment some counter when they start, and then decrement it when they end - you can only exit if the counter is 0. That way, if your design changes to allow multiple simultaneous background threads, you don't need to change your exit-checking code. Don't forget to perform the increment/decrement in a thread-safe way (e.g. using `AtomicInteger`) and make sure the decrement is within a finally block, so that the counter will still be decremented even if the thread throws an exception which isn't caught.

Comment: Right..now I know that what I did is completely  wrong. My concern is : how do I check if a thread is running? If I put Thread thRunning = Thread.currentThread();inside one of the thread code ..would that be correct?

Comment: @max: I've given you two options in the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Will `Thread.currentThread()` not be referring to your GUI thread? Therefore it will always be alive.

Answer (score 1):

The current thread is always alive. If it were dead it would be running the code to check if it was alive.  Perhaps you intended to save the other thread in a field and check if it was alive?

Answer (score 1):

Thread.CurrentThread().IsAlive() ALWAYS returns true, because you're interrogating the state of the thread on which you're running the code doing the checking. You'll need to keep a handle to the worker threads when you create them, and interrogate THEIR state in this method.

Comment: So  Thread thRunning = Thread.currentThread(); in the above thread I added would that mean checking the thread status? sorry for being unable to get the meaning of what you're suggesting

Comment: Basically, when you start off the new thread by clicking button A or B, keep a reference to that thread somewhere visible to your close handler (in the same window class, perhaps). Then, check `if((threadA != null && threadA.IsAlive()) || (threadB != null && threadB.IsAlive()))` instead of `if(Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive())`

Answer (score 0):

This checks, if the current thread (the one that executes the lines) is alive.

You could as well ask yourself: "Am I alive?" and the answer is clear (if you are not a zombie).